# Is every point of every open set E, the subset of R^2 a limit point of E?

Tags: real-analysis

I think this one is really trivial.

Since E is open, for every element e in E, there is a neighborhood N of e such that N is in E.
If radius of the neighborhood of e is r, then,
for any d(n,e) such that 0

Hence, e is limit point by definition.

Is this correct?

Comment: Should say that $N$ is a *subset* of $E$. The word "in" usually means element of. At this moment, not everything you intended to type has appeared. You want to show that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is a point $u$ in $E$, other than $e$, such that $d(u,e)\lt \epsilon$. Just let $u$ be any point other than $e$ in the disk with centre $e$ and radius $\min(r,\epsilon)$. It might be nicer to call the point $a$ instead of $e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is true, but your reasoning is incomplete.  Let $x \in E$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $N_\epsilon(x)$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$.  Then, $N_\epsilon(x) \cap E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and therefore cannot be a singleton.

Comment: @ Vectk :Why this set $N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap E$ can not be singleton

Comment: @Struggler Because singletons are not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.